# Determine if object is an instance of a generic base class, any generic type

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to test if a value is an instance of a generic base class, without knowing the generic type parameter. Using the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof) as the base of my example, this is what I'd like to accomplish:

```
using System;

public class Class1<T> { }
public class DerivedC1 : Class1<int> { }

class IsSubclassTest
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(
          "DerivedC1 subclass of Class1: {0}",
          typeof(DerivedC1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Class1<>)) // <- Here.
      );
   }
}
```

While this is syntactically correct, it always yields false. If I remove the generic type parameter, it works as expected (returns true).

**How can I test if a class type is a subclass of a generic base class, without knowing its generic type parameter as such?**

Comment: Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687264/check-if-object-is-of-non-specific-generic-type-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that `DrevidedC1` is *not* a sublcass of `Class1<T>`, it's a subclass of `Class1<int>`. Make sure you understand this subtle diference; `Class1<T>` is a open type (`T` can be anything, it hasn't been set) while `DerivedC1` extends a closed type `Class1<int>` (it's not open in `T` anymore, `T` is set to `int` and only `int`). So when you do the following:

```
 typeof(DerivedC1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Class1<>))
```

The answer is evidently `false`.

What you need to do is check if the *generic type definition* of `DerivedC1`'s base type (think of it as the corresponding open generic type of `Class1<int>`) equals `Class1<T>` which it clearly does.

The correct code is therefore:

```
typeof(DerivedC1).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Class1<>));
```

Or better yet, as Matías Fidemraizer states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184501/767890):

```
typeof(DerivedC1).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Class1<>)));
```

Comment: @JohnWhite Unless your checks may be implemented using reflection and types providing full type names, since you're strongly-typing your checks, there should be no issue with checking types from different assemblies.

Answer (score 6):

Changing `typeof(DerivedC1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Class1<>))` to `typeof(Class1<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DerivedC1).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())` should be enough in your case.

`Type.IsAssignableFrom` is more powerful than using `Type.IsSubClassOf` because it just checks if some type is assignable to other type. This includes, *the same type*, interface types and other cases.

Comment: What do you mean by _"should be enough in your case"_? I'm struggling to get this to work. Could it be that it's not adequate when the generic type argument is a type from another assembly?

Comment: @JohnWhite No, I mean that if you're using it in a single place, you shouldn't need to generalize the solution. You can use it *as is* ;P

Comment: @JohnWhite I would go with the `IsAssignableFrom` route, it also works to check interface types.

Comment: I'm certain there is something I'm missing. I copied the exact code you provided, ran regex matching after changing names to completely ensure I did everything right, but it just wouldn't return `true`. I have no idea what's afoot. Obviously, the code snippet in the question is a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnWhite Uhm, check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/toLtnT Here I provide you a working sample

Comment: I'm not usre the first method is correct. `typeof(DerivedC1).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` is *not* a sublcass of `Class1<>`, its `Class1<>` itself. The second method should work perfectly.

Comment: Wow. Man. I had the derived type and the base type swapped. Jesus Christ. For some reason I thought the derived should come first in the condition and didn't bother to check.

Comment: @InBetween But using `IsAssignableFrom` should work in either case

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Very true. I'd edit your answer though, as it stands now, the first option will return `false`.

Answer (score 5):

There's special methods on `Type` for this sort of thing. As far as I can see, you'll need to walk up your base-types and check each in turn until you either (a) hit a match or (b) get to the top of the inheritance hierarchy (i.e. `System.Object`).

As such, the following (recursive) extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDerivedFromGenericParent(this Type type, Type parentType)
    {
        if(!parentType.IsGenericType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("type must be generic", "parentType");
        }
        if(type == null || type == typeof(object))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == parentType)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return type.BaseType.IsDerivedFromGenericParent(parentType)
            || type.GetInterfaces().Any(t=>t.IsDerivedFromGenericParent(parentType));
    }
}
```

will allow you to do the following

```
typeof(DerivedC1).IsDerivedFromGenericParent(typeof(Class1<>))
```

***...and will also work if you test something derived from `DerivedC1`.***

Comment: @JohnWhite Could it be that you are testing for an interface implementation? I adjusted the code above to allow for this. Seems to work fine for a class derived from `List<>` and testing if it is `IEnumerable<>` both of which are definitely in a different assembly.