# Reflection: How to create a precisely filtered list of the Assembly's types?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

```
foreach (var item in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                             .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Item)))
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Can this be modified so that the list will include all classes that are derived from 'Item' even if they are two or more times removed? (ie: x.BaseType.BaseType == typeof(Item) etc.)

Also, could it be done to filter out all abstract classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach to this is to use [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (var item in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                             .Where(x => typeof(Item).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract))
{
    //Handle each item
}
```

Assuming my "Handle each item were a `Console.WriteLine(item)`, and I had this class structure:

```
class ItemBase {}
class Item : ItemBase {}
class SuperItem : Item {}
abstract class SuperSuperItem : SuperItem{}
class UltimateItem : SuperSuperItem {}
```

The output would be:

> Item
>
> SuperItem
>
> UltimateItem

Note that in this case `IsAssignableFrom` returns true for itself, which you can easily omit by adding `&& x != typeof(Item)` to the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
public static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var items = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                            .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.GetBaseTypes().Contains(typeof(Item)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetBaseTypes(this Type type) {
        if (type.BaseType == null) return type.GetInterfaces();

        return Enumerable.Repeat(type.BaseType, 1)
                         .Concat(type.GetInterfaces())
                         .Concat(type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany<Type, Type>(GetBaseTypes))
                         .Concat(type.BaseType.GetBaseTypes());
    }
}

public class Item { }
public class ItemA : Item { }
public class ItemB : ItemA { }
public abstract class ItemC : Item { }
```

The extension method for retrieving the base type was taken from [Given a C# Type, Get its Base Classes and Implemented Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823655/given-a-c-sharp-type-get-its-base-classes-and-implemented-interfaces)

The reason why this was done was that `Type` only has `BaseType()` and we need to iterate those recursively to ensure we get the types of the other classes in the chain.

The program yields `ItemA` and `ItemB`